# C++ templates and casting with base and sub class as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, casting

Sorry for the confusing title. I am not sure how to describe my problem better.

Please look at the following code:

```
template<class T>
class TmpClass
{};

class Base
{};

class Child : public Base
{};

int main()
{
    typedef TmpClass<Base*> A;
    typedef TmpClass<Child*> B;

    A a;
    B b;
    A* ap = &b; //this does not work
}
```

Why is the cast not working although the template parameter is derived?

Comment: because they are 2 different unrelated classes. While `Child` may be derrived from `Base`. `TmpClass<Child*>` is not derrived from `TmpClass<Base*>`

Comment: ok but is TmpClass<Child*> not completely comaptible to TmpClass<Base*>?

Comment: Yes the templates will generate 2 different classes. And depending on how you use T it can break a lot and cause much undefined behavior if they would be implicitly convertible.

Comment: ok thanks. i think i am getting the point. maybe i choosed a bad code design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it generates 2 different classes. Lets assume the following:

```
template<class T>
struct TmpClass
{
    T t;
    double d;
};

struct Base
{
    int i;
};

struct Child : public Base
{
    int i2;
};
```

*This is really basic and would even be more cluttered with virtual functions etc. This is just simplified for a possible issue which can occur.*

When you now instantiate the classes they look like this (t*he names are completely made up by me*)

```
struct _internal_TmpClass_Base
{
    Base t;
    double d;
};

struct _internal_TmpClass_Child
{
    Child t;
    double d;
};
```

Thing is:

The size of `Base` is `sizeof(int)`. The size of `Child` is `2*sizeof(int)`

If you want to access `d` in TmpClass, it is (depending on the template) at complete different memory locations. A `TmpClass<Child>` has `d` at the location after the size of `Child` (2*int). When you now cast it to a `TmpClass<Base>` and you want to access `d` it assumes this is in the memory after the size of `Base` (1*int) not `Child`. And you will read or write memory which you don't intent.

Those things are usually categorized as "Undefined Behavior"

Comment: I thought it would be better to show a bit more details. And this is just one example where things can go wrong.